# PL/SQL, Cannot print variable

Tags: sql, oracle, dbms-output

I'm trying to learn PL/SQL by simply assigning a variable from a select statement and then, to confirm it's working, print it sql output.

```
DECLARE ALLOW_STUFF NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT VAL_N INTO ALLOW_STUFF FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_KEY = 'ALLOW_ME';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ALLOW_STUFF);
END;
```

I'm using SQL Developer and/or SQL PLus.  When I run this, all I get is

```
Anonymous block completed
```

Rather than than the value of MY_TABLE.VAL_N

Comment: `set serveroutput on` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm#sthref952

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable output, otherwise the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE statements are ignored.
Output can be enabled using:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
```

For more information about DBMS_OUTPUT read Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000634

As stated in the comments also set serveroutput on can be used.

Comment: Tried that - same result.

Comment: Did you connect the DBMS output windows in SQLDeveloper? DBMS output won't appear in the ordinary script output window.

Comment: I had to also add set serveroutput on size 30000;